# Call javascript function from html in different locations

Tags: javascript, html, jdbc

I'm trying to call a javascript function that allow to print a div, defined as:

```
function printdiv(printpage) {
  var headstr = "<html><head><title></title></head><body>";
  var footstr = "</body>";
  var newstr = document.all.item(printpage).innerHTML;
  var oldstr = document.body.innerHTML;
  document.body.innerHTML = headstr+newstr+footstr;
  window.print();
  document.body.innerHTML = oldstr;
  return false;
}
```

That is inside a file 'main.js' in a js folder. The HTML file has a button that calls this function:

```
<input id="downloadScan" type="button" onclick="printDiv('document');" class="btn btn-default" value="Print">
```

And the same html file contains the location of the javascript function:

```
<script src="./js/main.js"></script>
```

But when I click the button, nothing happens. I tried to directly put the function inside the HTML file and it works. What is the problem?

Comment: You may want to consider writing a function that creates a div instead of trying to rewrite the whole page. Just a tip. Not sure that's you problem though.

Comment: I'd highly recommend using a standard method instead of `document.all` (which is extremely old and non-standard)

Comment: `document.body` is `<body>` so doesn't make sense inserting `<body>` inside `<body>` or `<html>` either

Comment: ok, but that's not the point. The function works when is inside the html file

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would place script tags in your page header (or in some cases body) however given they are not present at page load I fear it may be an execution order problem.

It appears as though you are trying to dynamically create pages, you can achieve this with out needing to create the entire structure of the page, and instead just dynamically creating the content (body). It also appears as though you are trying to maintain the contents of the body and do an "append".

Try the following setup:

> index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="./js/main.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input id="downloadScan" type="button" onclick="appendDiv('Some text not in a div');" class="btn btn-default" value="Print">

        <input id="downloadScan2" type="button" onclick="appendDiv('<div>Some content in a div</div>');" class="btn btn-default" value="Print">
    </body>
</html>
```

> main.js

```
function appendDiv(content) {
   document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML + content;
 }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/acvgout7/

Comment: yes, my script tag is in the footer. I tried with this solution but it doesn't work, when I click the button, nothing happens @Aidan

Comment: @Rudy I've added a JS Fiddle to show it working. You may have reference issues if your JS file is in the wrong place. Are you on linux or windows ? Is the JS file in the same folder as the HTML file? If it is in the same folder please change reference from ./js/main.js to main.js , if its in a subfolder called JS please try update reference to js/main.js instead of ./js/main.js     . If you are on linux its probably taking you out to the Root directory and cant find your JS file.